# SQLQuery.list() returns the same entries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, orm

In my java code I have written like this. This query returning same records again and again. But in database I have only single record.

```
String queryString = "select e.business_event_id, e.event_name from events e left outer join subscriptions s on (e.business_event_id = s.business_event_id and s.firm_id = :firmId and s.employee_id = :employeeId) where e.object_id = :objectId and e.category_type =:categoryType and e.is_enabled =:isEnabled";

queryString += " order by e.event_name asc";
final SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("firmId", firmId);
query.setParameter("employeeId", employeeId);
query.setParameter("objectId", objectId);
query.setParameter("categoryType", categoryType);
query.setParameter("isEnabled", "Y");       
final List<Object[]> list = query.list();
```

Here it is returning same entries again and again. If anyone knows means please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by again and again? Are you invoking this code again and again or your are getting more than one record in `list`

Comment: @RaviRanjan - What I meant is same entries coming repeatedly

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Any specific reason to use LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: You are not using any columns from the joined table `subscriptions`, why do you join it at all, if you only want to get information from the `events` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are joining a parent record with multiple child rows.

Since you only need to select records from the parent entity-side, you can simply use distinct:

```
"select distinct e.business_event_id, e.event_name from ..."
```

But you should also use the [`hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/) Hibernate query hint to avoid passing DISTINCT to the SQL statement.

### Update

As `@a_horse_with_no_name` says, you don't even need the left join with `subscriptions` since you don't select anything from that relation and you don't filter it either. By removing that join you won't get any duplicates and the `distinct` is not required any more.

Comment: Even better: Sangeetha could remove `subscriptions` from the query completely without changing the result. The `distinct` can then be removed as well.